# Explicit integration of PDE running very slowly

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning, timing

I would like to solve the PDE $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=(1-x)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$, in the interval $[0,1]$, with initial condition $u(0,x)=e^{-218(\frac{-2}{3}-ln(1-x))^2}$, by manually implementing a pseudospectral method with Chebyshev nodes for spatial discretization and a Taylor method for time integration. The first ListPlot appears in a matter of seconds, but after that the code keeps running forever, to the point that I do not even know if it produces the correct results at the end. Is the code correct, and if so, can it become quicker? Please let me know for any clarifications.

```
a=218;
b=-2/3;
x0=0;
x1=1;
u[x_,t_,a1_,b1_]:=Exp[-a1*(b1+t-Log[1-x])^2];
f[x_]:=u[x,0,a,b];
D[t,u]-(1-x)*D[x,u]

der1[x0_]:=NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1],x0,
"DifferenceOrder"->"Pseudospectral"]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
Nx=2^8;
II=IdentityMatrix[Nx];
n=Nx-1;
theta=N[Table[i*Pi/n,{i,0,n}]];
X=N[Chop[((x0+x1)/2)+((x0-x1)/2)*Cos[theta]]];
dt=N[0.01*(x1-x0)/n];
D1=der1[X];
L=(1-x)*D1;
L2=L.L;
L3=L2.L;
M = (II+dt*L+((dt^2)/2)*L2+((dt^3)/6)*L3);
M= Developer`ToPackedArray[M, Real];
Nt=10^5;
T=Table[it*dt,{it,0,Nt-1}];
U=ConstantArray[0.,{Nt, Nx}];
U[[1, All]]=f[X];
U= Developer`ToPackedArray[U, Real];
ListPlot[Transpose[{X, U[[1, All]]}], PlotRange->All, Joined->True]
Do[U[[it+1,All]]=M.U [[it,All]],{it,1,Nt-1}]
ListPlot[Transpose[{X,U[[Nt, All]]}], PlotRange->All, Joined->True]
ListPlot[Transpose[{X,U[[Nt, All]]-f[X-T[[Nt]]]}], PlotRange->All, Joined->True]
```

Comment: The time consuming step is: `Do[U[[it+1,All]]=M.U [[it,All]],{it,1,Nt-1}]`You could try Compilâtion or ParallelEvaluate.

Comment: @DanielHuber I see, thank you! Is the code running correctly for you? It is returning the two latter ListPlots empty for me

Comment: Sorry, but I do not have the time (and nerve ): ) to wait for the loop to end.

Comment: @DanielHuber Thanks anyway!

Comment: I'm missing a boundary condition `u[ 0,t]` or `u[ 1,t]` ?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann B.C.'s are not given, probably because we're meant to evolve this equation in time. Do the 2 latter listplots appear for you? I think there might be a mistake in the definition of the linear operator ```L=(1-x)*D1;```.If there is, would you happen to know how to define it properly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JBuck Sorry I didn't check your code in detail, I only tried to find an alternative solution using "MethodOfLines"

Comment: @JBuck Parameter `a` is not defined in your code. Also, please, pay attention that `x` in `L = (1 - x)*D1` is not defined as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are typos in the code that `x` in `L = (1 - x)*D1` is not defined and also in the initial data last point is `Indeterminate`. General structure of the code should be revisited as follows

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Needs["Developer`"]

b = -2/3; a = 218;
x0 = 0;
x1 = 1;
u[x_, t_, a1_, b1_] := Exp[-a1*(b1 + t - Log[1 - x])^2];
f[x_] := u[x, 0, a, b];
D[u, t] - (1 - x)*D[u, x]
  

der1[x0_] := 
  NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], x0, 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
Nx = 2^8;
II = IdentityMatrix[Nx];
n = Nx - 1;
theta = N[Table[i*Pi/n, {i, 0, n}]];
X = N[Chop[((x0 + x1)/2) + ((x0 - x1)/2)*Cos[theta]]];
dt = N[0.01*(x1 - x0)/n];
D1 = der1[X];
L = (II - DiagonalMatrix[X]) . D1;
L2 = L . L;
L3 = L2 . L;
M = (II + dt*L + ((dt^2)/2)*L2 + ((dt^3)/6)*L3);
M = Developer`ToPackedArray[M, Real];
Nt = Round[1/dt];
T = Table[it*dt, {it, 1, Nt}];
U[0] = Chop[f[X] /. Indeterminate -> 0] // Quiet;
```

Iteration on time takes about 0.25 s

```
Do[U[it] = M . U[it - 1], {it, 1, Nt}]
```

Visualization of function and logarithm of absolute error on several steps

```
    Table[{ListPlot[Transpose[{X, U[i]}], PlotRange -> All, 
   Joined -> True, PlotLabel -> i dt],
  ListPlot[Transpose[{X, Abs[U[i] - u[X, T[[i]], a, b] // Quiet]}], 
   PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]}, {i, 
  1, Nt, Round[Nt/10]}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Thank you so much! I next tried to plot the energy error $E(t)-E(0)$ as a function of t, where the energy is $\Int__{0}^{1} (1-x) (\partial_x u)^2 \,dx \$. I used the Clenshaw-Curtis integration rule ```h[x_]:=(1/n)*(1-Sum[2*Cos[2*i*x]/(4*i^2 - 1), {i, (n-1)/2}])
weights=h[X];
weights[[1]]=1/(2*n^2);
weights[[n]]=1/(2*n^2);
weights.U[0]
NIntegrate[f[x],{x,x0,x1}]
energy=ConstantArray[0.,{Nt}];
Do[energy[[it]]=weights.(D1.U[[it,All]])^2,{it,1,Nt}]
ListPlot[energy-energy[[1]]]```, to compute the energy,but  ```weights.U[0]``` is nowhere near the actual integral value, any clue why?

Comment: @JBuck Please, check that `weights . ConstantArray[1, Length[weights]]=0.704224`, and therefore `weights` is not defined as the weights of the Clenshaw-Curtis rule. We can use weights1 = NIntegrate`ClenshawCurtisRuleData[Nx/2, 20][[2]]`, but this is also not so precise since `weights1 . (Drop[U[0], -1] + Drop[U[0], 1])/2=0.0619452` , and we expecting about 0.0617043.  We should increase `Nx` up to 2^12 to get about  0.06172.

Comment: Nvm I found the mistake about the weights, they should be defined as ```h[theta]``` instead of ```h[X]```.  On the other hand, when I try to compute the energy ```energy=ConstantArray[0.,{Nt}];
Do[energy[[it]]=weights.(D1.U[[it,All]])^2,{it,1,Nt}]
ListPlot[energy-energy[[1]]]```, I get errors like ```Part::partd: Part specification U[[1,All]] is longer than depth of object```, do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @JBuck Ok! It looks much better `{weights . U[0], NIntegrate[f[x], {x, x0, x1}]}` is about `{0.0617043, 0.0617043}`. To calculate `energy` we can use `Do[energy[it] = weights . (D1 . U[it])^2, {it, 0, Nt}]; ListPlot[Table[energy[i] - energy[0], {i, 0, Nx}]]`

Comment: For some reason it returns an empty listplot with the error message "Set::write: Tag List in {0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,<<25450>>}[0] is Protected.", have I messed up something?

Comment: @JBuck Don't use  `energy=ConstantArray[0.,{Nt}];`! Run code first to compute `U` and `weights`. Also in the last line use  `Do[energy[it] = weights . (D1 . U[it])^2, {it, 0, Nt}]; ListPlot[[Table[energy[i] - energy[0], {i, 0, Nt}]]`.

Comment: I'm so sorry, after computing ```U``` and ```weights```, I run ```Do[energy[it] = weights . (D1 . U[it])^2, {it, 0, Nt}]; ListPlot[[Table[energy[i] - energy[0], {i, 0, Nt}]]]``` but this time I get the error ```Part::pkspec1: The expression {0.,-0.00141585,-0.00283164,-0.00424737,-0.00566305,-0.00707867,-0.00849424,-0.00990975,<<35>>,-0.0608313,-0.0622447,-0.0636581,-0.0650715,-0.0664848,-0.067898,-0.0693112,<<25451>>} cannot be used as a part specification.```, does this happen to you as well?

Comment: @JBuck Oh, there is a typo in my last comment with  `ListPlot[[]]`, plot with one pare `ListPlot[]` as follows  `ListPlot[Table[energy[i] - energy[0], {i, 0, Nt}]]`