# Change of variables in 2-nd order PDE

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I need to solve the following equation:

$-(1+x) \partial_t ^2 \psi + (1-2x^2)\partial_x\partial_t \psi +(1-x)x^2\partial_x^2 \psi -2x \partial_t\psi+x(2-3x)\partial_x\psi=0$

for the function $\psi(t,x)$, for $x \in [0,1]$, with initial conditions $\psi(0,x)=f(x), \dot{\psi}(0,x)=(1-x)f'(x)$, where $f(x)=e^{-218(\frac{-2}{3}-ln(1-x))^2}$. The idea is to use the change of variables $\pi = \partial_t \psi$ to reduce it to a system that is 1-st order in time, $\partial_t u=\hat{L}u$, where $u=\begin{bmatrix} \psi \\ \pi \end{bmatrix}, \hat{L}= \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 1 \\ \hat{L_1} && \hat{L_2} \end{bmatrix}$. The system will then be solved with a pseudo-spectral method for spatial discretization and a Runge-Kutta method for time integration, in the spirit of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/262101/explicit-integration-of-pde-running-very-slowly), but I'm having trouble with defining the new equation and the matrix $\hat{L}$ under the change of variables, in order to use it in the latter methods, can someone offer a proposal?

Comment: Have you seen [`DChange[]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80241/analogue-for-maples-dchange-change-of-variables-in-differential-expressions)? It might work on this.

Comment: What are interval of integration on `x` and `bc`?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Sorry, I edited the question to include them

Comment: @JBuck Boundary conditions are not defined. Should we integrate without `bc` with `ic` only?

Comment: Why not directly use `NDSolve`? Is it for didactic purposes?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sadly `DChange` can't handle transformations involving differentiation… I think this post is more related?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132668/1871

Comment: @AlexTrounev exactly, there are no bc's, sorry for the late reply

Comment: @xzczd yes, we're meant to learn how to program numerical differentiation by ourselves

Comment: Even the b.c. is not explictly given in the original problem, you still need b.c. for approximating infinite domain, just check the post under the tag [tag:boundary-condition-at-infinity]

Comment: @xzczd  I see what you mean but for some reason I see no boundary conditions stated in the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this problem we can use method of line with handmade discreditation on `x` as follows:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Needs["Developer`"]

b = -2/3; a = 218;
x0 = 0;
x1 = 1;
u = Exp[-a*(b + t - Log[1 - x])^2];
f[y_] := u /. {t -> 0, x -> y}; f1[y_] := D[u, x] /. {t -> 0, x -> y};
eq = -(1 + x) D[u, t, t] + (1 - 2 x^2)*
    D[u, x, t] + (1 - x) x^2 D[u, x, x] - 2 x D[u, t] + 
   x (2 - 3 x) D[u, x] // Simplify
  

der[x0_, k_] := 
  NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[k], x0, 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
Nx = 2^8;
II = IdentityMatrix[Nx];
n = Nx - 1;
theta = N[Table[i*Pi/n, {i, 0, n}]];
X = N[Chop[((x0 + x1)/2) + ((x0 - x1)/2)*Cos[theta]]];
D1 = der[X, 1]; D2 = der[X, 2];

L1 = (II - 2 DiagonalMatrix[X]^2) . 
  D1; L2 = ((II - DiagonalMatrix[X]) . DiagonalMatrix[X]^2) . 
  D2; L3 = (DiagonalMatrix[X] . (2 II - 3 DiagonalMatrix[X])) . D1;
m1 = II + DiagonalMatrix[X]; m2 = 2 DiagonalMatrix[X];
L1 = Developer`ToPackedArray[L1, Real]; L2 = 
 Developer`ToPackedArray[L2, Real]; L3 = 
 Developer`ToPackedArray[L3, Real]; m1 = 
 Developer`ToPackedArray[m1, Real]; m2 = 
 Developer`ToPackedArray[m2, Real];

Psi = Table[Subscript[psi, i][t], {i, Nx}]; Psi1 = 
 Table[Subscript[psi, i]'[t], {i, Nx}]; Pi0 = 
 Table[Subscript[pi, i][t], {i, Nx}]; Pi1 = 
 Table[Subscript[pi, i]'[t], {i, Nx}];
eq1 = -m1 . Pi1 + L1 . Pi0 + L2 . Psi - m2 . Pi0 + 
  L3 . Psi; eq2 = -Psi1 + Pi0;
F0 = Chop[f[X] /. Indeterminate -> 0] // Quiet; ic1 = 
 Table[Subscript[psi, i][0] == F0[[i]], {i, 
   Nx}]; F1 = (II - DiagonalMatrix[X]) . 
   Chop[f1[X] /. Indeterminate -> 0] // Quiet; ic2 = 
 Table[Subscript[pi, i][0] == F1[[i]], {i, Nx}];

var = Join[Table[Subscript[psi, i], {i, Nx}], 
  Table[Subscript[pi, i], {i, Nx}]]; sol = 
 NDSolve[Join[Table[eq1[[i]] == 0, {i, Nx}], 
   Table[eq2[[i]] == 0, {i, Nx}], ic1, ic2], var, {t, 0, 1}];
```

Visualization of solution and absolute error

```
Table[{ListPlot[Transpose[{X, Psi /. sol[[1]] /. t -> tn}], 
   PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, PlotLabel -> tn],
  ListPlot[
   Transpose[{X, 
     Abs[(Psi /. sol[[1]] /. t -> tn) - (u /. {t -> tn, x -> X}) // 
       Quiet]}], PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, 
   ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]}, {tn, 0.01, .91, .1}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Update 1. We also can implement Runge-Kutta method from my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/262154/manual-runge-kutta-2-for-a-system-of-4-odes/262180#262180) as follows

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Needs["Developer`"]

b = -2/3; a = 218;
x0 = 0;
x1 = 1;
u = Exp[-a*(b + t - Log[1 - x])^2];
f[y_] := u /. {t -> 0, x -> y}; f1[y_] := D[u, x] /. {t -> 0, x -> y};
eq = -(1 + x) D[u, t, t] + (1 - 2 x^2)*
    D[u, x, t] + (1 - x) x^2 D[u, x, x] - 2 x D[u, t] + 
   x (2 - 3 x) D[u, x] // Simplify


der[x0_, k_] := 
  NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[k], x0, 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
Nx = 2^8;
II = IdentityMatrix[Nx];
n = Nx - 1;
theta = N[Table[i*Pi/n, {i, 0, n}]];
X = N[Chop[((x0 + x1)/2) + ((x0 - x1)/2)*Cos[theta]]];
D1 = der[X, 1]; D2 = der[X, 2];

L1 = (II - 2 DiagonalMatrix[X]^2) . 
  D1; L2 = ((II - DiagonalMatrix[X]) . DiagonalMatrix[X]^2) . 
  D2; L3 = (DiagonalMatrix[X] . (2 II - 3 DiagonalMatrix[X])) . D1;
m1 = II + DiagonalMatrix[X]; m2 = 2 DiagonalMatrix[X];
L1 = Developer`ToPackedArray[L1, Real]; L2 = 
 Developer`ToPackedArray[L2, Real]; L3 = 
 Developer`ToPackedArray[L3, Real]; m1 = 
 Developer`ToPackedArray[m1, Real]; m2 = 
 Developer`ToPackedArray[m2, Real];

F0 = Chop[f[X] /. Indeterminate -> 0] // Quiet; F1 = (II - DiagonalMatrix[X]) . 
   Chop[f1[X] /. Indeterminate -> 0] // Quiet;  
z = ConstantArray[0, 2 Nx]; 
ff[t_, z_] := 
 Join[Drop[z, Nx], 
  Inverse[m1] . (L1 . Drop[z, Nx] + L2 . Drop[z, -Nx] - 
     m2 . Drop[z, Nx] + L3 . Drop[z, -Nx])];

rk2[ff_, h_][{t_, x_}] := Module[{k1, k2}, k1 = ff[t, x];
  k2 = ff[t + h/2, x + h k1/2];
  {t + h, x + h k2}]


tf = 1; dt = 1/1000; sol = 
 NestList[rk2[ff, dt], {0, Join[F0, F1]}, Round[tf/dt]];
```

Visualization of numerical solution (red points) and exact solution (blue lines) at different times (shown above)

```
Table[Show[
  ListLinePlot[Transpose[{X, (u /. {t -> i dt, x -> X}) // Quiet}], 
   PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> N[i dt]], 
  ListPlot[Transpose[{X, Drop[sol[[i + 1, 2]], -Nx]}], 
   PlotStyle -> Red, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Smaller}]], {i, 1, 
  Round[tf/dt], 100}]
```

[image: Figure 2]